# how can we add multiple marker with click event in google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using the below code but i'm little confuse with click event. How, can i add click event on every marker??

> ```
>         var address = 'Dubai';
>      var neighborhoods = [
>        new google.maps.LatLng(25.23247465817403, 55.30191340351564),
>        new google.maps.LatLng(25.244586082480332, 55.29822268391115),
>        new google.maps.LatLng(25.230844181976337, 55.32225527668459),
>        new google.maps.LatLng(25.224787936110832, 55.28526224995119)
>      ];
>      var markers = [];
>      var iterator = 0;
>      var map;
>      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
>      function initialize() {
>          var mapOptions = {
>              zoom: 12,
>          };
>          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'),
>                  mapOptions);
>          geocoder.geocode({
>              'address': address
>          },
>          function (results, status) {
>              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
>                  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
>              }
>          });
>      }
>      function drop() {
>          for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
>              setTimeout(function () {
>                  addMarker();
>              }, i * 200);
>          }
>      }
>      function addMarker() {
>          var image = 'img/flagred.png';
>          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
>              position: neighborhoods[iterator],
>              map: map,
>              icon: image,
>              title:"Hello World!",
>              draggable: false,
>              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
>          }));
>          iterator++;
>      }
> ```

I have looked at the other answers here but that didnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add it to every marker you add to your map. So change the addMarker-definition to

```
function addMarker() {
     var image = 'img/flagred.png';
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: neighborhoods[iterator],
         map: map,
         icon: image,
         title:"Hello World!",
         draggable: false,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
     });
     markers.push(marker);

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         // your magic goes here
     });

     iterator++;
 }
```

Comment: i have updated your code but after that map is not showing here!!

Comment: My mistake, forgot a `);` after `your magic goes here`

Comment: Yep!! It's working here!!